# GridLayoutManager how to display different view type on next row

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager, linearlayoutmanager

How to configure `GridLayoutManager` to display different `viewtypes` in different rows?

For example I have 2 `viewtypes`  and `RecycleView` displays the following:

```
[category] [category] [category]
[category] [item] [item]
[item] [item] [item] [item]
```

And what I want is:

```
[category] [category] [category]
[category]
[item] [item] [item] [item]
[item] [item]
```

The structure is very simple, first show `categories`, then `items`, if `categories` ended, jump to next row.

Is there any out of the box configuration for `GridLayoutManager` to achieve this behavior? or I should write my own `LayoutManager`?

Comment: You have to check **is it category or not?** If not than do as you wanna do

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find out of the box solution so in the end I just added blank `[category]` to complete the row.

However good solution probably will be custom `LayoutManager`, but in my case it's over complicated related to the task.

**If someone will post solution with `LayoutManager` I will mark his answer as accepted.**